# Perform segue from navigationcontroller using segue

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this code on a page:

```
@IBAction func showKaart(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuToKaart", sender: sender)
}
```

And the segue "menuToKaart" does go to the right place but the problem is that it's not using the Navigationcontroller because it's 1 page up. Because of that I am not able to go back.

[image]

(sorry if the picture is unclear)

What I am trying to do is this:

Inside ViewController2 is a button called "Kaart" which leads to the viewcontroller "Kaart"

I want a button inside Table View "Locaties" to use the same segue as the button "Kaart" in ViewController2. This works with the code I am using but it doesn't use the navigation controller so there is no navigationbar where I can press back to go back to "ViewController2"

Comment: what do you mean it's 1 page up?

Comment: Well the segue "menuToKaart" is `Menu > Kaart` but the navigationcontroller is in front of Menu so actually it's supposed to be like `Navigationcontroller > Menu > Kaart`

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now. Can you please show a photo of how the segues are embedded? Feel free to cover the confidential parts of the views.

Comment: I editted my question with a picture and explanation.

Comment: Each view controller needs its own segues to the Kaart controller. You can not use the same Segue in two different controllers. You could use the same name but in separate controllers. If you want navigation you have to push Locaties onto a navigation stack or present Locaties as the root of a new UINavigationController. It would be worth you updating your question with the view controller transitions you want as I think in writing it you might answer your own question.

Comment: @Sinan Samet you want to go like Navigationcontroller > Menu > Locaties>kaart

Comment: Sorry for the very late reaction I didn't have time to work on it. But yes that's what I want to achieve @vigneshkumar. And thanks Rory McKinnel I will take a look at it.